# How to use the control_click function with pyautoit?

Tags: python, autoit

I am trying to simulate mouseclicks with python, without using my actual mouse. I have found the autoit library and the control_click function seems to do exactly what I want. However, I am not really sure how to use the parameters? I have read through so many posts and not a single one helped me really out. This is the best I have so far:

```
autoit.control_click("Bluestacks App Player", "", "[CLASS:BlueStacksApp; INSTANCE:1]", click=1,x=500,y=500)
```

The error that I get: `autoit.autoit.AutoItError: send click message failed`

I have tried to use the AutoIt3 Window Info program, but the text where the controlID is supposed to be is just a blank box...what am I supposed to do?

Comment: You forgot `button` (`"left"`) (or as I prefer because it works for left-handed-people too: `"primary"`). You can't skip an optional argument if you use the following optional argument(s) too.

Comment: And when phyton doesn't parse the arguments in its own way, in AutoIt the syntax would be `ControlClick("Bluestacks App Player", "", "[CLASS:BlueStacksApp; INSTANCE:1]", "primary",1,500,500)`